# Trying to get global y coordinate of datagrid selecteditem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Here's the situation: 
I have a populated datagrid and I want to move a form to be inline (same y position) with the datagrid's selectedItem.  I cannot rely on a mouseClick event because the selected item may change with a keyboard event.  The datagrid does not have an itemRenderer, just plain old dataField.
Anyone done this before?

**Here's some stubbed out example code for all those interested based on Jacob's answer.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;
            import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;

            [Bindable] public var ac_POitems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable] public var selectedY:int;

            protected function dg_POitems_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //TODO
            }

            protected function submit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                //TODO
            }

            protected function format_sqlite_date(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
                df.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY";
                var value:Object = item[col.dataField];
                return df.format(value);
            }

            protected function dg_POitems_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.itemRenderer.y);
                selectedY = event.itemRenderer.y;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5">
        <mx:DataGrid id="dg_POitems" dataProvider="{ac_POitems}" creationComplete="dg_POitems_creationCompleteHandler(event)" 
                     editable="true" height="100%" change="dg_POitems_changeHandler(event)">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Consumer" dataField="consumer" editable="false"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Description" dataField="description" width="300" editable="false"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Amount" dataField="item_cost" editable="false" width="55"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Service Date" dataField="service_date" labelFunction="format_sqlite_date"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Invoice Date" dataField="invoice_date" labelFunction="format_sqlite_date"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Paid Date" dataField="payment_received" labelFunction="format_sqlite_date"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:Form id="form_POItemDateEditor" label="{dg_POitems.selectedItem.consumer}" x="{dg_POitems.x + dg_POitems.width + 10}" 
             y="{selectedY + 10}" visible="{dg_POitems.selectedItem}" borderColor="#ffffff">
        <s:Label text="edit {dg_POitems.selectedItem.consumer}" width="100%" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" fontWeight="bold" textDecoration="underline"/>
        <mx:FormItem label="Service Date">
            <mx:DateField id="service_date"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Invoie Date">
            <mx:DateField id="invoice_date"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Paid Date">
            <mx:DateField id="payment_received"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem>
            <s:Button id="submit" label="Submit" click="submit_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Don't forget to check an answer to accept it. It's good for your reputation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        protected function datagrid1_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.itemRenderer.y);

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{steps}" change="datagrid1_changeHandler(event)" >
    ....
```

---

**Edit** Showing listener for `spark:List` `valueCommit` Event.

```
protected function valueCommitHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.currentTarget.layout.getElementBounds(list.selectedIndex));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob...simple as that!  I'll post some sample code below based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `DisplayObject's` [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#localToGlobal%28%29) function. It will allow you to convert the ItemRenderer's 'y' position (that is with respect to the parent container, probably a List) to a global 'y' position (with respect to the Stage).

[globalToLocal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#globalToLocal%28%29) will do the opposite.

You'll have to do some additional calculations from here on, but those will depend on what your application display hierarchy looks like, so I can't be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find full code for exactly what you want to do right here http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2009/11/flex-template-component.html

Comment: I was cooking up a little example and using a Spark List (or DataGrid) to do it. It would be a lot harder to get a hold of the ItemRenderer that was clicked, since there is no longer an ITEM_CLICK event. Any ideas on that issue?

Comment: @RIAstar use the `valueCommit` event.

Comment: And the IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE doesn't have a reference to the ItemRenderer anymore (as ListEvent.CHANGE used to have).

Comment: @Jacob valueCommit doesn't have a reference to the ItemRenderer either. It's just a FlexEvent.

Comment: A simpler way to do this may be to have your renderer fire an event when it enters the selected state. You can then use event.target and the localToGlobal/globalToLocal to do the positioning.

In some way Flex 4 is a huge step forward, but in places where they removed needed functionality (or just made it hard to find), it doesn't feel that way sometimes.

Comment: @RIAstar you can use the `layout.getElementBounds()` method. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution, although it requires a custom ItemRenderer. The only alternative I can see is using list.dataGroup.getElementAt(i), but that could get tricky.

Comment: @RIAStar getElementAt is really buggy in Flex 4.1.  I'm not sure if they've fixed it in 4.5, but in 4.1 it you could ask for some number < numElements and get a null pointer exception when virtualization was on (because it counted the number of things in the dataprovider in numElements, NOT the number of elements it had actually created).